# Can drivers installed on a OS be used by UEFI?

Tags: drivers, uefi

I'm a little perplexed what happened here. I just finished building a PC. Powered it up and went into the UEFI options. During this time the resolution was set for 800x600, and I was getting small graphical glitches on the screen (tiny little dots) .

I finished installing Windows and booted to desktop with the graphical glitches still happening. Downloaded the latest drivers for the card and installed them. The computer rebooted and I went into UEFI options. The resolution was now 1024 x 768 and the graphical glitch was gone. Booting into Windows had the resolution set to 1920 x 1080 with the graphical glitch gone.

The only conclusion I could come up with is that the drivers I installed for Windows were now being used by the UEFI. Is that possible?

Comment: Probably not, unless the drivers also rewrote the BIOS. What may have happened was that when you rebooted the computer (during the windows installation) the BIOS was able to detect what monitor was attached and it's capabilities. With the changed screen resolution, the video didn't have any problems.

Comment: @LDC3 It persisted all the way though the Windows installation and the first time it booted to the desktop in Windows without the driver though

Comment: Maybe the computer needed to power down to save the information in BIOS. While you were installing Windows, the computer never powered down. Also, Windows does a system check when it is first configured. The information on screen resolution could have been updated then, but I doubt that any downloaded drivers would have been written to BIOS.

Comment: The driver install might well have updated the video card's firmware, particularly if it was a plug-in video card and you used drivers from the card or chipset manufacturer's Web site.

Comment: Windows does not use the UEFI for graphical services. What are your video card and monitor?

Comment: @harrymc XFX RADEON R7 260X and a normal 32 inch HD TV ( The PC is a HTPC )

Comment: Something you did fixed the problem, maybe even resetting a loose connection. One can invent theories to explain it, but without a way to test they have no value.

Comment: I think this is actually related to UEFI GOP. The fact that your GPU have UEFI firmware.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me explain what you experienced.  On a desktop computer, the UEFI uses [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) to determine what resolutions the monitor supports.  EDID is a 20-year-old technology, and it's not always consistent.  As an example, if the monitor was turned on after the computer was turned on, you might experience this problem.  As [stated here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh997769.aspx), the UEFI will default to 1024×768 if EDID data is not properly received.

As for your broad question of whether device drivers can be used by the UEFI, the short answer is **no**.  However, there are instances where a driver installation package may also contain a firmware upgrade.  Firmware is not a driver, but it could effect how a device functions with the UEFI.

If you downloaded your graphics drivers from Intel, AMD, or nVidia, these would not include firmware.  If you downloaded your graphics driver from the system or card manufacturer (e.g. Dell, MSI, etc.), it may of contained a firmware upgrade, but this is very uncommon.

Comment: Firmware is not a driver; but UEFI drivers are not always flash supported firmware. UEFI drivers can be stored and loaded from the UEFI System partition

Answer (score 0):

No, the UEFI and OS are separate, so unfortunately, unless the UEFI is specifically designed to read installed windows(or other OS) drivers from the hard drive, it is not possible.

Your graphics card drivers may have updated the firmware of the card to make it work with your UEFI.

Comment: Highly unlikely that the driver had updated the firmware itself, but it could maybe have changed some parameters on the card.

Answer (score 0):

Since the **Windows Driver Model** and the **UEFI Driver Model** are different, they require different driver files.  Therefore, it is not possible to change UEFI when only installing the windows driver file.

In your case, you should consider that UEFI drivers are really not tied to FLASH as they can also be loaded from the UEFI System Partition located in your HDD. Then your card manufacturer driver update application can very well update both; the Windows driver located somewhere under `C:\Windows\` *and* the UEFI driver somewhere within the UEFI partition; in doing so there would be a UEFI driver update with no firmware "flash" action involved at all.